# Is there now a 1u (or for that matter 2u) solution for PCs with graphics cards?

Tags: rackmount, nvidia

For rack PCs, with nVidia (or similar) graphics cards (so, 1060s etc),

we use normal 4u rack mounted PCs.

So if you have 4 or 8 of them in a rack it's obviously a huge amount of height space.

In fact, these days (2018) is there a realistic rack PC that is 1u, but can take a normal nVidia card.

Of course, it has to run server-style 24/7 heat wise.

Comment: Contact your enterprise account manager at a major vendor.

Comment: Thanks; I find unfortunately they know absolutely nothing. Whereas on sites like this, you find true expertise and experience.

Answer (score 3):

Most decent GPUs use double-slots, which simply can't fit into a 1U server, not and have decent air throughput anyway. There are lots of 2U servers which will support a pair of double-slot GPUs (HPE DL380, Cisco UCS C240 etc.) - so perhaps try to use those. That said neither of them officially support GTX/RTX cards, though lots of them support Quadro and Tesla cards.

Comment: We have 2U servers with four Tesla cards. But the downside is, there is not much space to get airflow through. These machines are **LOUD**. You can hear them boot 40 meters down the corridor through a closed door.

Comment: gotchya.  i did a bit of googling - so this sort of thing is crap .. https://www.gigabyte.com/Press/News/1393 ??

Comment: I'd be very worried about cooling capabiity tbh.

Answer (score 0):

[IBM's AC922](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/power-systems-ac922) is 2U with up to 6 Nvidia GPUs on an accelerated bus and runs standard LTS Linux distros. Currently the same machine type as the IBM Summit super computer at Oakridge (first in the TOP500 supercomputers).

Comment: Ah - you know, i specifically meant nVidia "graphics cards" - such as the 1060, 1070 etc.  Graphics cards as in your "gaming PC" ... I believe your referenced one is for nVidia math processing setups.......  i think.

Comment: I tend to assume people who ask for rack servers aren't doing it for home gaming, my bad - such a different world i live in sometime. It is a cool (not energy consumption) grunty big beast however :-)

Comment: gotchya, it is for (very!) unusual situation with huge rack of 3D VR headsets.  (they only work with a, eg, 1060 nVidia card.)  we end up with absurdly huge piles of racks and cabinets  :/